# angular material material design horizontal nav tabs convert to mobile menu when browser window size changes

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have created AMD page with horizontal tabs using `<md-tab>` and i want it to be mobile menu when i change browser size to small size then resize to normal and vice versa like bootstrap mobile menu.is that possible ??? thank you in advance.

I have created main page as follows:
**Index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="angular-material/angular-material.css">
    <style >
 .mainApp md-content .ext-content {
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #FFF2E0; }
  </style>
</head>
<div id="logo" > <a href="favicon.ico"></div>
<body ng-app="mainApp">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout="column" ng-cloak>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="views/home.html" ></script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="views/aboutus.html"></script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="views/services.html"></script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="views/contactus.html"></script>

   <md-tabs md-stretch-tabs="always" class="md-primary" md-selected="selectedIndex">

    <md-tab data-ui-sref="home" md-active="state.is('home') ">
    <md-tab-label>HOME</md-tab-label>
    </md-tab>

    <md-tab data-ui-sref="aboutus" md-active="state.is('aboutus')">
    <md-tab-label>ABOUT US</md-tab-label>
    </md-tab>

    <md-tab data-ui-sref="services" md-active="state.is('services')">
    <md-tab-label>SERVICES</md-tab-label>
    </md-tab>

    <md-tab data-ui-sref="contactus" md-active="state.is('contactus')">
    <md-tab-label>CONTACT US</md-tab-label>
    </md-tab>
<!--     <md-tab id="tab1" label="HOME" aria-controls="tab1-content" md-nav-click="goto('home')"></md-tab>
    <md-tab id="tab2" label="ABOUT US" aria-controls="tab2-content" md-nav-click="goto('aboutus)"></md-tab>
    <md-tab id="tab3" label="SERVICES" aria-controls="tab3-content" md-nav-click="goto('services')"></md-tab>
    <md-tab id="tab4" label="CONTACT US" aria-controls="tab4-content" md-nav-click="goto('contactus')"></md-tab>
 -->  </md-tabs> 

  <div id="content" ui-view flex> </div>

    </div>

    <script src="angular/angular.js"></script> 
    <script src="angular-material/angular-material.js"></script> 
    <script src="angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script> 
    <script src="angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script> 
    <script src="angular/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controller/controller.js"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

**controller.js**

```
(function(angular, undefined) {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('mainApp', ['ngMaterial',  'ui.router'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
        $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: "/home",
            templateUrl: "views/home.html"
        })
        .state('aboutus', {
            url: "/aboutus",
            templateUrl: "views/aboutus.html"
        })
        .state('services', {
            url: "/services",
            templateUrl: "views/services.html"
        })
        .state('contactus', {
            url: "/contactus",
            templateUrl: "views/contactus.html"
        })
        ;
    })
    .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,$state, $location, $log) {
        $scope.selectedIndex = 0;
        $scope.$watch('selectedIndex', function(current, old) {
            switch (current) {
                case 0:
                    $location.url("/home");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $location.url("/aboutus");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $location.url("/services");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $location.url("/contactus");
                    break;
            }
        });
    });

})(angular);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can show and hide elements based on screen size - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/kkrOPP?editors=1010#0)

In your code you would swap `md-tabs` with `md-menu` or `md-menu-bar`.

Check the [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdMedia) for more info on $mdMedia.

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp" layout-fill layout="column" layout-align="center center">
  <div style="width:200px; height:100px; background:red" ng-if="!mobile"></div>
  <div style="width:100px; height:200px; background:blue" ng-if="mobile"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $window, $mdMedia) {
  resizeProgress();

  angular.element($window).bind("resize", function() {
    resizeProgress();
    $scope.$apply();
    });

  function resizeProgress () {
    if ($mdMedia("gt-xs")) {
      $scope.mobile = false;
    }
    else if ($mdMedia("xs")) {
      $scope.mobile = true;
    }
  }
});
```

For the menu to work you could do something simple like this:

Markup

```
<md-menu-item><md-button ng-click="showPage(0)">Home</md-button></md-menu-item>
<md-menu-item><md-button ng-click="showPage(1)">About Us</md-button></md-menu-item>
....
```

JS

```
$scope.showPage = function (page) {
   $scope.selectedIndex = page;
};
```

However, if you were going to do that I would suggest changing the name **selectedIndex** to something like **selectedLocation**.

Comment: i really appreciated for it but will it make my md-tabs to mobile menu i.e all pages home aboutus service and contact pages in single mobile menu ????

Comment: Sir, I want the normal view as tab, that ls like SPA and when i reduce browser size, all tab should get converted to mobile menu like bootstrap responsive mobile menu. it is not possible with <md-tabs> ?? please co-operate i am new to AMD,i hope it is not annoying to you.

Comment: @amarghodke As far as I am aware there isn't an automatic change from tabs to menu for small screen size in Angular Material.

Comment: ok sir,appreciated your feedback,but using  md-menu or md-menubar will it work like and look like SPA ??

Comment: @amarghodke Yes it will.

Comment: can you do me a favor? will you edit my code ?? in plunker or codepen ??

Comment: @amarghodke I'm a bit busy at the moment unfortunately. Check out the demos - https://material.angularjs.org/latest/ - they're very easy to follow.

Comment: if you got free time please update on plunker or codepen i will compare with my code.

Comment: hello sir, can you answer to this question posted by me today ? i have created menu as per your recommendation .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463460/angular-material-design-menu-bar-does-not-route-page-without-any-errors